# Can't create db in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Trying to build a Rails project but when I go to create a db I get this error:

> could not connect to server: No such file or directory    Is the server
>   running locally and accepting     connections on Unix domain socket
>   "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

I uninstalled the `pg gem` and reinstalled it but I am still getting the error.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue?

Resolution:

**First Way**

I can't up vote yet but the solution that worked for me was to run:

`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast`

and then to:

`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start`

I am now able to create a db in my rails app.

Thanks @Panayoitis Georgiou (&everyone)!

**Second way**

If you want to manually start and stop postgresql (installed via homebrew), the easiest way is:

`brew services start postgresql`

and

`brew services stop postgresql`

Comment: i think, u have to run your pg server ! Try this one and let me know: `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start`

Comment: If you are on a Mac, you can get a self-contained Postgres DB/app from http://postgresapp.com/. Once installed, it runs like any other app. Easy way to get going with PG. But, as 7urkm3n noted, you need to have your DB server running in order to create the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command to manually start the server:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

**if that is not woking try the following**

For pure installing postgresql on Mac OS, the process will be (using brew command):

```
brew install postgresql
```

then if you want to automatically run postgresql at login:

```
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

or else you just want to run it anytime you want:

```
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

If your case is more complicated, let's brew uninstall postgresql and redo these steps.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the above suggestions. When I try to manually start the server I get this:  `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
server starting` but I dont have any other servers running

Comment: try this
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast

Comment: also 
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8

Answer (score 1):

I can't up vote yet but the solution that worked for me was to run:

`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast`

and then to:

`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start`

I am now able to create a db in my rails app.

Thanks @Panayoitis Georgiou (&everyone)!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Glad you made it. Don't forget to mark the answers 'accepted' that worked for you ;)